# map.putall(fromMap) throws exception : Attempt to dereference a null object

Tags: apex, batch, map

I'm trying to copy entries from a map IdValueMapforDB into a static variable IdValueMap, in the execute method. But it always throws an exception on the line IdValueMap.putAll(IdValueMapforDB);.

Below is my class :

```
public class UpdateOnDBBatch implements Database.batchable<MyWrapperClass>, Database.AllowsCallouts, database.stateful{ 
       public static map<id , map<String, String>> IdValueMap;
       list<MyWrapperClass> listForUpdate;
       map<id , map<String, String>> IdValueMapforDB;

       public UpdateOnDBBatch(list<MyWrapperClass> clList)

   {

       listForUpdate = new list<MyWrapperClass>();
       listForUpdate = clList;

       IdValueMapforDB = new map<id , map<String, String>>();

   }

   public Iterable<MyWrapperClass> start(Database.batchableContext info){ 

       return listForUpdate;

   }     

   public void execute(Database.batchableContext info, List<MyWrapperClass> scope){ 

       for(MyWrapperClass clDBRecord : scope)
       {

           map<String, String> innerMap = new map<String, String>();
           innerMap.put(clDBRecord.FieldName, clDBRecord.FieldValue);
           IdValueMapforDB.put(clDBRecord.accountId,innerMap);


            map<String, String> FieldValueMap = new map<String, String>();
            FieldValueMap.put(clDBRecord.fieldName, clDBRecord.FieldValue );

            if(IdValueMapforDB.size() > 0){ 

                if(IdValueMapforDB.containsKey(clDBRecord.accountId))
                {
                    map<String, String> oldFieldValueMap = IdValueMapforDB.get(clDBRecord.accountId);
                    oldFieldValueMap.putAll(FieldValueMap);    
                    IdValueMapforDB.put(clDBRecord.accountId, oldFieldValueMap);

                        IdValueMap.putAll(IdValueMapforDB);
                }
                else
                {
                    IdValueMapforDB.put(clDBRecord.accountId, FieldValueMap);

                        IdValueMap.putAll(IdValueMapforDB);
                }
           }

       }

   }     

   public void finish(Database.batchableContext info){ 

       if(IdValueMap != null && !IdValueMap.isEmpty()){
       updateCl(IdValueMap); 

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only declared the Map and never initialized it before adding values into it. You have to initialize the IdValueMap in the start method or Constructor as below and you will not get the Exception.

```
IdValueMap = new Map<id , map<String, String>>();
```